# GNUPLOT with point-size variables stored in a different file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file with the following format :

```
y1  y2  y3  y4  ... 
1.3 1.1 0.5 0.5 ...
0.2 0.4 0.6 0.1 ...
```

I know how to use Gnuplot to plot the data in this file. Suppose I have 50 columns, then I use:

```
plot for [col=0:150] filename using 0:col with lines ...
```

Now, I want to make a scatter instead of a line plot with points having variable size. I have a different file storing the pointsize variables. I know I need to also use a for loop and:

```
w p ps variable
```

However, since the point-size variables are stored in a different file, I do not know how to write the using specification. Normally one uses

```
using 0:1:2
```

where the point size variables are stored in the second column etc. But what if these variables are stored in a different file ?

I think I can solve this problem by combining both the data and the pointsize variables file into a single file, but I wonder if one can do this using gnuplot.

Thanks

Comment: How are the point size values stored in the second file? As 1 row with 50 columns or as 1 column with 50 rows?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a one-to-one matchup of lines in the two files, then yes. Assuming  `file.dat` is formatted like the one you show above, and `ps.dat` contains one header record and then in column 1 the point size for all points in that same line of the data file:

```
# read point sizes into a data block in gnuplot
set datafile columnheaders
set table $pointsize
plot "ps.dat" using 1 with table
unset table

# Now plot the data, using the value of $pointsize[j+1] for row j of points
# There are two  tricky bits here 
# 1) the line numbers are counted starting with 0
#    but array and datablock entries are counted starting from 1.
# 2) $pointsize is an array of strings. We need to convert this to a
#    real number in order to use it as a point size
plot for [i=1:*] "file.dat" using 0:i:(real($pointsize[$0+1])) with points ps variable
```

file.dat

```
y1 y2 y3 y4
1 2 4 3
2 3 5 4
3 4 6 5
4 5 8 6
```

ps.dat

```
ps
1
5
2
3
```

[image]